# Sum of even in Scheme

Tags: list, functional-programming, scheme

This is my first experience with Scheme. I have a list with integers and I wanna get the sum of all even number in list.

```
 ; sum_even
(define (sum_even l)
  (if (null? l) l
  (cond ((even? (car l)) 0)
        ((not(even? (car l))) (car l)))
  (+ (sum_even (car l) (sum_even(cdr l))))))
(sum_even '(2 3 4))
```

Comment: So what exactly do you want to do? Get the sum of all even numbers in the list or get the sum of all even indices?

Comment: the sum of the even numbers. (sum_even '(2 3 4 6)) = 12

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
(define (sum_even l)
    (cond ((null? l) 0)
          ((even? (car l)) (+ (car l) (sum_even (cdr l))))
          (else (sum_even (cdr l)))))
```

Not tested

Answer (score 4):

You're not exactly asking a question. Are you checking if your solution is correct or looking for an alternate solution?

You can also implement it as follows via

```
(apply + (filter even? lst))
```

edit: If, as you mentioned, you can't use filter, this solution will work and is tail-recursive:

```
(define (sum-even lst)
    (let loop ((only-evens lst) (sum 0))
        (cond
            ((null? only-evens) sum)             
            ((even? (car only-evens))
             (loop (cdr only-evens) (+ (car only-evens) sum)))
            (else (loop (cdr only-evens) sum)))))
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, but I should solve this problem without filter function

Comment: Thank you again. I prefer simple solutions. Lambda and let expression make me nervous, especially for simple tasks. Wish you all the best ; )

Answer (score 3):

```
(define (sum-even xs)
  (foldl (lambda (e acc) 
           (if (even? e) 
               (+ e acc) 
               acc))
         0 
         xs))
```

Example:

```
> (sum-even (list 1 2 3 4 5 6 6))
18
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another one with higher order functions and no explicit recursion:

```
(use srfi-1)

(define (sum-even ls) (fold + 0 (filter even? ls)))
```

Comment: I think that is slower than just `foldl`, because you create a new list with `filter`, then fold it, reading every element once again.

Comment: O(2n) ist still O(n). Yes there is a intermediate list created. But this list could be eliminated by the compiler: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deforestation_(computer_science) . I do not know if any compiler for scheme does this automatically. Another version without intermediate lists looks like: (define (sum-list ls) (fold (lambda(x a) (if (even? x) (+ x a) x)) 0 ls))

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the built-in filter function. For example:

```
(filter even? l)
```

will return a list of even numbers in the list l. There are lots of ways to sum numbers in a list (example taken from http://groups.engin.umd.umich.edu/CIS/course.des/cis400/scheme/listsum.htm):

```
;
; List Sum
; By Jerry Smith
;
(define (list-sum lst)
   (cond
     ((null? lst)
       0)
     ((pair? (car lst))
      (+(list-sum (car lst)) (list-sum (cdr lst))))
     (else
       (+ (car lst) (list-sum (cdr lst))))))
```

Comment: Yes, this should be atom sum? Thank you for solution!